# Problem with tkraise showing wrong frame tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm trying to display 2 frames by using `tkraise()` but it doesn't work. It shows both two frames i don't know what the problem is. Please help me thank you

Code

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

class HomePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.main_label = tk.Label(text="WELCOME TO FOOD ORDER APP")
        self.main_label.config(font=("Arial", 20), fg="blue")
        self.main_label.place(x=300, y=0)

        self.order_new_button = tk.Button(text= "Order new table", width= 20, height= 10)
        self.order_new_button.place(x= 100, y = 100)
        self.order_old_button = tk.Button(text= "Add food for booked table", width= 20, height= 10)
        self.order_old_button.place(x= 400, y=100)

class ReorderPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.main_label = tk.Label(text="Order")
        self.main_label.place(x=200,y= 300)

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title = "Food Order"
        self.geometry("1040x600")
        self.resizable(height=False, width= False)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill= "both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (HomePage, ReorderPage):
            frame = F( container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        
        self.showPage(HomePage)

        
        
    def showPage(self, showFrame):
        self.frames[showFrame].tkraise()

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You aren't telling Tkinter to make any of your widgets children of the two frames (that would be the first parameter to the widget constructor).  Instead, you are letting them default to being children of the root window.  Your Frames are empty, so raising one over the other makes no visible difference.

Comment: i'm new to Tkinter and Python. I didn't understand too much :( pls point me what should i do

Answer (score 0):

> Problem with tkraise showing wrong frame tkinter

> > but it doesn't work. It shows both two frames i don't know what the
> > problem is.

You must add `self` for every widgets. Otherwise, it doesn't belong to classes.

Don't use wildcard `from tkinter import *`. Use this `import tkinter as tk`. Then `prefix tk`.

I add `ScrolledText` and `Button` widgets in `ReorderPage()` function.

```
Snippet:
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from tkinter import font as tkfont

class HomePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #self.controller = controller

        self.main_label = tk.Label(self, text="WELCOME TO FOOD ORDER APP")
        self.main_label.config(font=("Arial", 20), fg="blue")
        self.main_label.place(x=300, y=0)

        self.order_new_button = tk.Button(self, text= "Order new table", width= 20, height= 10,
                                          command=lambda: controller.showPage("ReorderPage"))
        self.order_new_button.place(x= 100, y = 100)
        self.order_old_button = tk.Button(self, text= "Add food for booked table", width= 20, height= 10)
        self.order_old_button.place(x= 400, y=100)

class ReorderPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        #self.controller = controller

        self.main_label = tk.Label(self, text="Order", font=controller.title_font)
        self.main_label.place(x=200,y= 300)

        self.st = ScrolledText(self, width=50,  height=10)
        self.st.place(x=200,y= 350)
        
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="HomePage",
                           command=lambda: controller.showPage("HomePage"))
        self.button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")
        self.title = "Food Order"
        self.geometry("1040x600")
        self.resizable(height=False, width= False)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill= "both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (HomePage, ReorderPage):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        
        self.showPage('HomePage')
        
        
    def showPage(self, showFrame):
        self.frames[showFrame].tkraise()
         

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]